# What are the main changes (improvements) in ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ros developers,
I am using ROS for gazebo simulations, algorithms implementation, communication with robots. I also used it with arduino. I think current versions almost can do anything. But what is this ROS2 about?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227211/what-are-the-main-changes-(improvements)-in-ros2?/) by [srikanthmalla](https://answers.ros.org/users/26013/srikanthmalla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see if the articles at the [ROS 2.0 Design](http://design.ros2.org/) site answer your question(s).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1